# How to fix `array literal error' when merging formulas?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I made a Google sheet with a pivot formula. To replace the empty cells with zeros, I have written formula. The formula is merged from 3 individual formulas. The formulas work individually, but after merging I get an Array Literal error. What am I missing?

link to the Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17De4sUlkBmDKoFw4DR9serilGFcKQCur2PlvQ6RaMKk/edit?usp=sharing

Merging the formulas gives an array literal error message, where I expect a working outcome

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 QUERY(A3:E; "select A,sum(D) where A !='' group by A pivot B"; 1)<>""; 
 QUERY(A3:E; "select A,sum(D) where A !='' group by A pivot B"; 1); 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks a  million Player0!  A less complex formula does the job